# Unable to resolve the current Docker CLI context "default": context "default": context not found: on Windows

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Docker and Kubernetes are popular with millions of developers and programmers.  So I  imagine this will be resolved quickly here.

I am studying linkedin tutorials as well as some codecademy videos on youtube.  Going over the same topic with different instructors provides clarity by having the same topic explained by different views.

Prior to going through the **current** tutorial, I was able to successfully run

```
kubectl describe namespace default
```

and

```
kubectl get namespaces
```

But suddenly all that is broken and I am not sure how to fix it.   And I just figured out what went wrong and I will answer my own question

Answer (score 65):

Try to update your active context of docker which Minikube will pick up.

**Command**

```
docker context use default
```

**Output**

```
default
Current context is now "default"
```

Comment: Please don't use all bold text in your answer. There really isn't any reason to do so, it just makes your post hard to look at and may distract from other answers.

Answer (score 0):

A tutorial demanded that I turn on Hyper-V but you have to reboot to use Hyper-V.  By rebooting, you shut down Docker Desktop which needs to be running because it serves the necessary role as the VM.